# Forcing a "hard" screen resolution resize

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, resolution

I have this weird monitor, that every now and then goes into what i call 'green-mode'. It's kind of hard to describe what that is, but when it does, alot the pixels go "green" and the image becomes blurry, sort of. I've confirmed this to be an error in the monitor, and not the GFX card.

I can get it to snap out of 'green-mode' and go back to being completely normal by either logging out and back in again, or by switching user.

For a long time (running Windows) I was able to achieve the same effect, simply by changing the resolution forth and back. This *has* previously worked in Ubuntu, but it doesn't any longer. I've had the same thing happen in Windows, where it's normal resolution resizer, didnt do the job, but then after an update, it worked again.

I'm running NVIDIA drivers.

Is there anyway to get Ubuntu doing the same?  It feels as if the resizing isnt done "hard" - you can sort of tell if the entire screen goes black while resizing, or if it just resizes.

Comment: Sounds like more of a driver issue to me. Did you try updating your NVIDIA drivers?

Comment: That's weird. I've updated it (or tried different versions) 3 or 4 times. And when I try it out this time - it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like updating graphics card driver fixed this issue.

I would suggest to wait for a while & continue using it before you are sure that the problem is fixed and then you can mark this answer as accepted.